# Disambiguating a Lax Monoidal Functor

Tags: haskell, typeclass, category-theory

I am trying to make a lax monoidal functor (Haskell's `Applicative`) that is as true to category theory as possible.  Mostly as an exercise to practice categorical thinking.  I've already made a few classses I am happy with to set up for this and now I have to make the class itself.  I've left all these building blocks at the foot of the post for reference.

So here is my process:
To start there is obviously a functor

```
class
  ( Functor cat1 cat2 f
  )
    => MonoidalFunctor cat1 cat2 f
```

The functor is between two *monoidal*-categories so we add those too.

```
class
  ( Functor cat1 cat2 f
  , MonoidalCategory cat1 bf1 i1
  , MonoidalCategory cat2 bf2 i2
  )
    => MonoidalFunctor cat1 cat2 bf1 bf2 i1 i2 f
```

Now since `i1` and `i2` are determined by `cat1` and `bf1`, and `cat2` and `bf2` respectively, we can add a fundep

```
class
  ( Functor cat1 cat2 f
  , MonoidalCategory cat1 bf1 i1
  , MonoidalCategory cat2 bf2 i2
  )
    => MonoidalFunctor cat1 cat2 bf1 bf2 i1 i2 f
    | cat1 bf1 -> i1
    , cat2 bf2 -> i2
```

Now to comlete the class we need to add two natural transformations, equivalent to the haskell functions `fzip` and `pure` so we will call them that.

```
class
  ( Functor cat1 cat2 f
  , MonoidalCategory cat1 bf1 i1
  , MonoidalCategory cat2 bf2 i2
  )
    => MonoidalFunctor cat1 cat2 bf1 bf2 i1 i2 f
    | cat1 bf1 -> i1
    , cat2 bf2 -> i2
  where
    fzip :: (f x `bf2` f y) `cat2` f (x `bf1` y)
    pure :: i2 `cat2` f i1
```

Before we even compile this I can already see an issue.  We don't mention `cat1` anywhere in these two functions!  And I can't derrive `cat1` from any combination of the other types in the class. Which means that `fzip` and `pure` are ambiguous to haskell.  Now it seems that we cannot infer `cat1` from anything that we already have, that is it should not have a fundep. While a fundep would resolve this issue it is not justified in terms of the mathematics.

Now I could use proxies to resolve this issue.  But I think that it might be possible to get away without them.  `fzip` and `pure` are not the way a Haskell applicative are defined even though they are minimal.  I am wondering if a `liftA2` or `(<*>)` analogy, might be mention all the required types needed to make this unambiguous.

**Is there a restructuring to make this class unambiguous without sacrificing the theory?**

---

Resources:

```
import Data.Kind
  ( Type
  )


class Category cat where
  id :: cat a a
  (.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c

-- | Isomorphism are morphisms with an inverse.
-- It is expected that for any @i :: Iso cat a b@:
-- 
-- prop> (fwd iso) . (bwd iso) = id
-- prop> (bwd iso) . (fwd iso) = id
--
-- That is to say `Iso`s should be isomorphisms.
data Iso cat a b = Iso
  { fwd :: cat a b
  , bwd :: cat b a
  }

instance
  ( Category cat
  )
    => Category (Iso cat)
  where
    id = Iso id id
    f . g = Iso (fwd f . fwd g) (bwd g . bwd f)

class
  ( Category s
  , Category t
  )
    => Functor (s :: a -> a -> Type) (t :: b -> b -> Type) (f :: a -> b)
  where
    map :: s x y -> t (f x) (f y)

class
  ( Category cat1
  , Category cat2
  , Category cat3
  )
    => Bifunctor
      (cat1 :: a -> a -> Type)
      (cat2 :: b -> b -> Type)
      (cat3 :: c -> c -> Type)
      (p :: a -> b -> c)
  where
    bimap :: cat1 x y -> cat2 z w -> cat3 (p x z) (p y w)

class
  ( Bifunctor cat cat cat p
  )
    => MonoidalCategory
      (cat :: a -> a -> Type)
      (p   :: a -> a -> a)
      (i   :: a)
      | cat p -> i
  where
    associator  :: Iso cat (x `p` (y `p` z)) ((x `p` y) `p` z)
    leftUnitor  :: Iso cat (i `p` x) x
    rightUnitor :: Iso cat (x `p` i) x
```

Comment: cat1 is "mentioned" as the domain of `f`, all hope is not lost. I think you will need `f -> cat1` fundep, at least, probably many more. Consider associated types.

Comment: @luqui It is also mentioned as the category, which `bf1` makes monoidal.  But sadly neither of these uniquely determine `cat1`.

Comment: You want a functor which can simultaneously have multiple source categories?  I think you may need to lower your bar a little if you want this to come out clean. There is nothing in CT which requires such a functor, afaik. (Sure they are "punned" sometimes, but you can always translate to a version where functors have unique source and target categories)

Comment: @luqui Sorry I am not familiar with the CT theorem(s) you are referencing.  I was under the impression that a functor could easily have multiple source categories.  It seems trivial to me.  Could you expand a bit or link to something relevant?

Comment: Ok. Another option is to set `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications`, then you can model things in full generality (this teaches one to appreciate hindley-milner's inference balance)

Comment: It's not a theorem, it's in the definition.  A functor *from C to D* is defined as.... If you want a different domain and codomain, it's a different functor.  If you happen to use the same letter for it, you are playing notation games. The story is simplified also in haskell because we can't really do subcategories.  What such functor do you have in mind?

Comment: @luqui Most `Functor (->) (->)`s are also `Functor (Iso (->)) (Iso (->))` and `Functor (Iso (->)) (->)`.  It is sort of inconvenient to have to make a new version of say `Maybe` if I want to use it on a groupoid.  (Of course in this case `Iso (->)` is a subcategory, we just can't enforce it)

Comment: Yes it is inconvenient, but not formally unsound, as far as I know.  I have never found a general treatment of CT in haskell that is anywhere near convenient -- "it compiles!" is often a big win. Anyway your question claimed it was about not sacrificing the theory, but now we get to the truth: you want it to be pretty. This is a matter of style and there is a large space of aesthetic decisions to explore. Anyway based on what you are saying I'd recommend playing with `AllowAmbiguousTypes`/`TypeApplications`